# Monotonic roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, roots

Consider we have a stricktly increasing positive sequence $\lambda_n$ and the following sixth order algebraic equation for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\zeta s^6-s^4+\lambda_n^2=0,$$

where $\zeta$ is a positive constant. I am wondering whether all of the six roots of this algebraic equation are monotone or not (in case of having an imaginary root we look at the absolute value)? How can we pass the monotonicity of a parameter, like $\lambda_n$, in the equation to the roots of that equation?

Comment: How do you handle complex numbers?

Comment: Your equation may not have all roots real numbers.

Comment: We can just look at both real part and imaginary part, or more simply we can deal with them by looking at the absolute value of an imaginary root.

Comment: Why don't you replace s<sup>6</sup> by t<sup>3</sup> and s<sup>4</sup> by t<sup>2</sup> ? t is equal to s<sup>2</sup>. The you could calculate the roots.